# What does a gate electrode do in the context of a quantum dot?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, chemical-potential, quantum-dots

I am trying to understand the creation of qubits through the use of quantum dots, but I have always had some trouble understanding the function of the gate. I know it can control the chemical potential of the dot itself, but how does it actually work?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of quantum dots. The ones discussed here are formed using *split-gate* technique: one first confines electrons in two dimensions by means of crystal growth, e.g., in GaAs/AlGaAs heterostructure. Then metallic gates are then deposited on the top of this structure, so that one can deplete the two-dimensional electron gas under the gates by applying a negative potential to them - via simple Coulomb repulsion (see, e.g., Fig 2 in [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610433)). The overall shape of the confining potential then depends on the relative potentials applied to the gates, whereas by adjusting the potential of all the gates simultaneously, one can control the average electron density in the region (including, the number of electrons in the quantum dot). In *this* case the gates should not be confused with the *leads* - the regions that serve as "wires" carrying electrons to and from the quantum dot in case of transport experiments.